# (sed or an alternative in sh) if a line does not contain a dot (.). Then add XX at the end

Tags: shell, regular-expression, csv

Background information: Data exchange via csv between 2 programs.

I have the following csv from program 1:

> ```
> > timestamp; name ; value 
> > 1655709562;Var 1 Float;65.0 
> > 1655709562;Var 2 Float;3.32 
> > 1655709562;Var 1 Integer;**2** 
> > 1655709562;Var 2 Integer;**564**
> ```

For program 2 I have to convert it to the following, because it always expects the same datentype at "value":

> ```
> timestamp; name ; value
> 1655709562;Var 1 Float;65.0
> 1655709562;Var 2 Float;3.32
> 1655709562;Var 1 Integer;**2.0**
> 1655709562;Var 2 Integer;**564.0**
> ```

I'll try to show it with a for loop and an if function, because I think that's the best way to show it.

```
for $line in $file
do
 If $line contains NOT "." 
  then
    add ".0" at the end of line
 end_if
done
```

Comment: If the `***` are not part of your file, please remove them. Also, do you just need to change the number, or do you also need to change the type (`Integer` => `Float`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sed`, the syntax for that is:

```
sed '/\./!s/$/.0/' < file.in > file.out
```

That is, if the current line does *not* (`!`) match the `\.` regex (a literal dot), `s`ubstitute the first match of the `$` regex (`$` matches at the end of the line) with `XX`.

Same with `awk`:

```
awk '! index($0, ".") {$0 = $0 ".0"}
     {print}' < file.in > file.out
```

Here using  `index()` to do a substring search. You could also do a regexp matching like with `sed` with `! /\./` instead.

With `perl`:

```
perl -lpe '$_ .= ".0" if index($_, ".") < 0' < file.in > file.out
```

Or with regexps:

```
perl -lpe '$_ .= "XX" unless /\./' < file.in > file.out
```

With `perl`, you can add the `-i` option to edit the file in place (in which case you have to pass its path as argument instead of opening it on its stdin). Some `sed` implementations have borrowed that option. Recent versions of the GNU implementation of `awk` have `-i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk`¹ for that.

In all those, a `.0` would also be added to the header line as as that line doesn't contain `.`s either.

Maybe a better way would be to add `.0` if the line ends in `;` followed by one or more decimal digits:

```
sed '/;[0123456789]\{1,\}$/ s/$/.0/'
```

Or with some `sed`s:

```
sed -E '/;[0123456789]+$/ s/$/.0/'
```

```
awk '/;[0123456789]+/{$0 = $0 ".0"}
     {print}'
```

```
perl -lpe '$_ .= ".0" if /;\d+$/'
```

---

<sup>¹ **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed help.
I have used the following string:
 sed '/\./!s/$/\.0/' -i $file

I have included the header only for explanation. Normally it does not exist in the CSV file

Comment: @MarAlz, the correct syntax in `sh` and with GNU `sed` would be `sed -i -- '/\./!s/$/.0/' "$file"` or `sed -i -e '/\./!s/$/.0/' -- "$file"`. Options should go before non-option arguments. In sh/bash, parameter expansions must be quoted. `--` should be used to mark the end of options, `.` should not be escaped in the replacement, using `\.` there would yield unspecified behaviour.